# Can not get data from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How to display values from a database on a page for display, I do not try how much I get this error.

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

development.erb.html

```
<% @development.each do |developer| %>
  <p><% @developer.email %></p>
<% end %>
```

---

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @development = TeamMember.all
  end
end
```

---

model.rb

```
class TeamMember < ApplicationRecord
end
```

---

db schema.rb

```
create_table "team_members", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email"
  t.string "first_name"
  t.string "last_name"
  t.string "team_text"
  t.string "image_url"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `<%= developer.email %>` instead of `<% @developer.email %>`

Comment: This helped me get rid of the error, but it did not help me to get the data, it's empty, tell me why?

Comment: Yes, name of your file should be named according to the action name i.e index.html.erb . And please note another change which i have mentioned in my answer <%= developer.email %> . You have missed use of  `=` in erb .

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the file name inside the welcome folder to index.html.erb instead of development.erb.html

Answer (score 0):

You should change your .erb file to:

```
<% @development.each do |developer| %>
  <p><%= developer.email %></p>
<% end %>
```

When you use `<% %>` to run ruby code inline, it won't output the result (ideal for .each), however when you want the resulting value (the developer's email) to be output into the HTML, you should use `<%= %>`.

In addition, the file should be found at /views/welcome/index.erb.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: `index.html.erb` not `index.erb.html` :)